# the codes are not working in the second xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

i am just working on a test app.

this is the xml file of the home page.

```
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivityTEST2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:text="Button12" />

       </RelativeLayout>
```

i have added a button listener to go to other page. here is my code for that.

```
 package com.example.test2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivityTEST2 extends Activity {

    Button but;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_test2);
    but=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button12);
    but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.activity123);
        }
    });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_test2, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

when i add a button listener in the second page to display text in the textfield, nothing works.

xml file of the second page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

when i add a button listerner to display text in the textfiled, nothing works.
the app neighter stops working nor does anything after that.

my second window's java content is

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.example.test2.R;



public class activity_main_activty_test2 extends Activity {
    Button but2;
    EditText edit1;

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity123);

            edit1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
            but2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
            but2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    edit1.setText("hellow");
                }
            });

          }



     @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_test2, menu);
            return true;
        }
}
```

am i missing something. do i have to address something. please help i am just a biggener.

Answer (score 2):

`i have added a button listener to go to other page` No, apparently you haven't.

You cannot go to the other activity through this code

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity123);
```

You need to use `Intent`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivityTEST2.this,activity_main_activty_test2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish(); //optional
}
```

**ALSO** remove `import com.example.test2.R;` from your second activity.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to go to the next view, you dont use  `setContentView(R.layout.activity123);` in your button listener it will not transfer you to the next activity, instead make use of intent since you have a 2nd activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), activity_main_activty_test2.class);
startActivity(intent)
```

in your `MainActivityTEST2`

```
but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), activity_main_activty_test2.class);
        startActivity(intent)
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry but that did not work. it is diosplaying a page with button and edittext . when i press the button nothing appears

Comment: check your layouts if you have the correct xml file name and if you use the correct Resource  setContentView(R.layout.activity123); in here. next time use descriptive file/variable names. even it is just a test it will make it harder for you to trace your error.

Answer (score 0):

Please Change your first page as following. Android use Intent to jump the activity from one to another.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivityTEST2 extends Activity {

Button but;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_test2);
 but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
 but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, activity_main_activty_test2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
  }
 });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_test2, menu);
return true;
 }
```

}

Comment: i am getting a red line under .setClass wht to do